# How to align a Bootstrap Dropright menu such that it opens upwards (unlike the default downwards direction)?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, bootstrap-4

My drop-right menu drops towards the right correctly, but downwards, which causes it to hide under my page. I want it to open upwards instead of downwards.

I tried fiddling around with CSS, adding `bottom:0` to the `dropdown-menu`, but it didn't work. I have also tried nesting a `dropdown-menu-right` in a `dropup` but the displayed menu is not in line with the button (it is at the top-right diagonal).

This my complete code for the dropdown:

```html
              <div class="dropright" style="position: relative;">
                <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block" style="font-size: large;" onblur="this.nextSibling.style.display='none'" onclick="this.nextSibling.style.display='block'" >
                  <img src="/assets/Images/Avatar.jpg"  class="rounded-circle" style="height:30px;width:30px; padding: 0;" alt="Avatar">
                </button>
                <div class="dropdown-menu" style="position: absolute;">
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="">Action</a>
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="">Another action</a>
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="">Something else here</a>
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="">Something else here</a>
                </div>
              </div>
```

[This](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GarJmPefLRlkM6cqsM6scAFY-Mvx5Dse/view?usp=sharing) is what I want

[This](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kNZhhvGsJKVKcuHEPT1DdTVeskgWaE-e/view?usp=sharing) is the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you expecting like

```css
.dropup .dropdown-menu {
    top: auto;
    left: 35px;
    bottom: 100%;
    margin-bottom: -36px !important;
 }
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Dropdowns</h2>
  <p>The .dropup class makes the dropdown menu expand upwards instead of downwards:</p>
  <br><br><br>
  <div class="dropup">
    <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">
    <span class="caret"></span></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href=" ">APPLICATIONS</a></li>
        <li class="divider"></li>

      <li><a href=" ">Bitbucket</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Jira </a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: yes indeed. but this one will not be very easy to use in a responsive design I believe. I wanted a bootstrap solution for my problem, which would also work for responsive designs.

Comment: We can achieve it by writing media query, tell me the contrains (in which device (laptop,tablet...) What size of dropup u r no expecting).

Comment: Primarily desktops and laptops. I wanted the drop-down to appear just besides the the button(towards the right), inline with its bottom. Just as displayed in your snippet. I just want t to be responsive, and not stay a certain pixel distance away from the button.

Comment: oh i think i just figured it out. The following css worked for me:

.dropup .dropdown-menu {
  top: auto;
  left: 100%;
  bottom: 0%;
}

Thanks for your help

Comment: If you think that my solution helped to get the answer then you can accept my answer  by clicking on tick mark beside the answer